# How to find the direction of the derivative in case of chain rule

Tags: calculus

If I have $z = f(x,y)$ and $x = u(t)$ and $y = v(t)$,

Then, derivative of $z$ w.r.t $t$ can simply be calculated using the following:

$$ \frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} * \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} * \frac{dy}{dt}$$

In this case, how do we point out the direction for the above derivative, in case we've a graph plotted for $z = f(x,y)$ in 2-d coordinate system.

Comment: You may notice that in your case $f(u(t),v(t))$ is a curve which doesn’t possess directional derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael Hoppe stated in the comments, $z=f(x,y)=f(u(t),v(t))$ has only one variable. This means that the direction of the derivative on a 2D graph of $z$ vs $t$ would just be the vector $[1,\frac{dz}{dt}]$.

If we are looking for the direction that $t$ forces $x$ and $y$ to go on the 2D plane of $x$ and $y$, we can see that the curve that is traced out is defined by the parametric $(u(t),v(t))$ and so the direction at a time $t$ would be the vector $[u'(t),v'(t)]$.

Comment: I am interested in plotting direction of the derivative $\frac{dz}{dt}$ in a graph of 2d coordinate system b/w $x$ and $y$ where the curve is plotted out and we're trying to mark the direction of the derivative at any particular point on the curve. I hope I make sense

Comment: I see. I updated the answer. Does this make sense now?

Comment: thank you for the answer. Why are we not including the term $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ in case of the x-component of the derivative, and similarly not including the partial term in y component of derivative

Comment: My question is why are we not using the terms $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ in each of the terms in the vector $[u'(t),v'(t)]$ (respectively).

Comment: As I stated before, those represent changes in $z$, not changes in $x$ and $y$. If you wanted to include the change in $z$ in your direction (note that this would be 3D then), then we could write $[u'(t),v'(t),\frac{dz}{dt}]$ which would include the partial terms.

Comment: In your second last comment, please change to "are not considering". I got confused because of the typo :)

Comment: Sorry about that. Im afraid its too late to edit that so Ill just delete it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76108/discussion-between-killerx-and-isaac-browne).